# Change context of an alertable / waitable thread

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, code-injection, dll-injection

I want to inject a piece of code into a running module using thread suspension method.

1. SuspendThread
2. GetThreadContext
3. DoSomething
4. ResumeThread

My question is what would happen if the thread I'm currently injecting is in alertable / waitable mode(WaitForSingleObject, GetMessage). what would happen once i hit the ResumeThread command.

Comment: Consider reading [The SuspendThread function suspends a thread, but it does so asynchronously](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150205-00/?p=44743) and [Why you should never suspend a thread](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031209-00/?p=41573).

Comment: I'm not sure how suspending a thread relates to injecting code, and I second IInspectable's objections.  But SuspendThread/ReleaseThread shouldn't affect API calls if you're using them properly.  (For example, WaitForSingleObjectEx might conceivably return immediately with WAIT_IO_COMPLETION, but if you're handling this case properly, it won't matter.)

Comment: @IInspectable, did you even read the links you're waving here around with? Raymond Chen says that *"to make sure the thread really is suspended, you need to perform a synchronous operation that is dependent on the fact that the thread is suspended"* and immediately gives an example of such method: *"The traditional way of doing this is to call `Get­Thread­Context`"*. Guess what? That's what OP wrote he does. Consider reading links you're telling other people to read **before** you suggest they consider reading them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, that's unfortunate. Code injection using `SetThreadContext()` is a well-established method, used for over a decade (at least), and to use `SetThreadContext()` safely (or as safely as it can be used) you have to first suspend the thread you're messing with. It's even mentioned in the MSDN documentation for the function, but maybe I'm expecting too much here. [code injection setthreadcontext](https://www.google.com/search?q=code+injection+setthreadcontext) [code injection suspendthread](https://www.google.com/search?q=code+injection+suspendthread)

Comment: @conio: the OP didn't mention SetThreadContext, so I would hope he is using the preferred method of injecting code, CreateRemoteThread.  SetThreadContext is for debugging, the documentation does NOT mention using it for code injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing that would have happened otherwise, I assume.

---

Lets say the target thread is currently in user mode. You save all the registers for later, set `RIP` to point to your code and call `ResumeThread()`. At some point your code start to execute, does whatever it does, restores all the registers the injection code saved, and lets the program resume its normal operation.

Now lets say the target thread is waiting. Waiting means the thread performs a system call that tells the scheduler not to schedule the thread for execution until something happens (an event is signaled, etc.). You save the registers of the user mode context (the way they were when `sysenter` was called), set RIP to point to you code and call `ResumeThread()`. That all well and nice, but the scheduler still won't schedule it for execution until the terms of the wait are satisfied.

When the wait finally ends, the thread does finished its business in kernel-mode, returns to user mode, and instead of executing the `ret` command following the `sysenter` goes on to perform your code. Finally your code restores all the registers and jumps to the saved `RIP` (from `ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject` or whatever) and everything continues as normal.

Finally, lets say you were performing an alertable wait. The story goes on pretty much as in the previous two paragraphs (you don't really need me to repeat that a third time, do you? :)), except that before the wait function returns it executes all the user APCs queued for the thread - **exactly as it would have happened without your intervention** - and then goes on to execute your code etc.

---

So basically what happens is what you should have expected to happen:

- If you called `SetThreadContext()` the user-mode context is changed and the computer behaves accordingly, regardless of whether the thread was waiting or not.
- If the thread was waiting for something it continues waiting for the same thing, regardless of whether you called 'SetThreadContext()' or not.
- If the thread was in an alertable wait, before the system call returns it makes sure the user APC queue is empty (either because there were user APCs and it called them or because the queue was empty and the 'regular' wait condition finally happened). This, again, regardless of whether you called `SetThreadContext()` or not.

Comment: Sounds like asking for disaster to me.  The interaction between the user-mode part of WaitForSingleObject and the kernel isn't documented, so when the kernel next schedules the thread and the context has been changed so that the rest of WaitForSingleObject never runs ... well, the outcome will be unpredictable.  Why not use CreateRemoteThread like everybody else?

Comment: Obviosly this is low level development but non the less is important to some domain specific applications (security applications, applications which interact with kernel drivers, etc.) good answer, +1.